# Multi-Threading & Method in class missing positional arguments, although they are passed

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have a table with different cells that I want to color for 0.2 seconds whenever the value on them changes (red if the new value is lower, green if its higher). So my idea is every time a new value is read from the database, create a new thread that just changes the color of the cell to red/green for 0.2 secs, then changes it back to white, and then kills that thread so that I don't end up with 1000000 different threads:

```
class DataStream(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        #(HERE GOES CODE LISTENING TO SOME DATA, IRRELEVANT FOR DISCUSSION)
        if doc['new_val'][new] > doc['old_val'][new]:
            flag = 1
        elif doc['new_val'][new] < doc['old_val'][new]:
            flag = -1
        queue = Queue()
        flash = ColorCells(queue,flag,ui.parameters.item(maturity_dates.index(exp),h_headers.index(new)))
        flash.daemon = True
        flash.start()

class ColorCells(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue,flag,item):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.flag = flag
        self.item = item
        self.run(self.flag,self.item)

    def run(self,flag,item):
        if flag == 1:
            colorb = QtGui.QColor(0,255,0)
        elif flag == -1:
            colorb = QtGui.QColor(255,0,0)
        item.setBackground(colorb)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))
        self._stop()
```

For your info, I'm using it together with PyQt, hence the item variable and the ui.parameters.item(x,y) to indicate the cell I want to change the color to.

The error I'm getting is that I'm missing 2 positional arguments in the run() method (flag and item). I would also like to know if I'm correctly killing the thread using self.stop() within ColorCells.run(). Thanks!

Comment: Qt does not support gui operations outside the main thread. But in any case, they are not needed here. Use QTimer instead.

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro, but I wanted to create a different thread every time I want to color a cell so I dont have to wait 0.2 seconds to continue with the code. There are like 10-20 updates every second, so if there is a way of coloring these cells in a parallel way that would be perfect.

Comment: There is no way to do gui operations in parallel. And to repeat: *Qt does not support gui operations outside the main thread*. But anyway, it really seems pointless to make 10-20 *separate* gui updates per second. Human visual processing just isn't fast enough to see them all. The right approach is to calculate batches of changes in a single worker thread and then send those changes to the gui using a custom signal. Since cross-thread signals are thread-safe, the gui can then be updated in a slot connected to the signal. Or it might be possible to do things even more simply using a QTimer.